# NoMethodError in Store#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following error, please any one view it and help me out of this..
Actually this is the error shown in my development.log file.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `quantity' for #<LineItem:0xaa47b1c>):
4: <tr>
5: <% end %>
6: <tr>
7: <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
8: <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
9: <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
10: </tr>
  app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_line_items__line_item_html_erb___826332857_89103730'
  app/views/carts/_cart.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_carts__cart_html_erb___185026047_87767060'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___370633105_87583010'
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6:in `hidden_div_if'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___370633105_87583010'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error's quite clear: your `LineItem` class does not have a method (or database field) called `quantity`.

Comment: 'rails generate migration add_quantity_to_line_items quantity:integer'
I used this in the command line already to create database field quantity...should I do any thing more..

Comment: Have you actually updated the database with `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I resolved the error, even though I gave quantity field , it didnt go into the database. I deleted the migration field and then re-generated it. Thanq

Comment: Yup, sounds like you didn't run `rake db:migrate`. Glad to help. (Remember you can mark my answer as "Helpful" by clicking the up-arrow; and "Accepted" by clicking the tick.)